# "cordova.file" Undefined in Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel-xdk

I´m trying to use cordova file plugin for my app (Android) in Intel XDK but when I make a simple verification like "console.log(cordova.file);" the console shows me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined"

I separated the code to isolate the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="js/app.js"></script>     
<script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script> 
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        if (window.Cordova) {
            document.addEventListener('DeviceReady', onDeviceReady, false);
        } else {
            console.log("Not ready yet");
        }
    }, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(cordova.file);  <---ERROR HERE        
    }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I included in my projects the cordova plugin-file, plugin-file-transfer and inAppBrowser. Also I included a cordova.js file downloaded by separated because my project didnt have it, I removed it because it wasn't helping at all.

I saw that some people modifies config.xml but I dont have that file in Intel XDK. My Intel XDK version is 3522 and the plugin file version is 4.2.0

Please somebody help me I´m stuck and this is the only issue I must solve to finish a project

Thanks

UPDATE: I saw that the problem is that the OnDeviceReady is never fired, what can I do?

Comment: You actually need that `cordova.js` file. Also, you don't need to download that file since it is generated during build. Simply adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">` to your html file will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Dar, I did what you said but in device nothing happens. I saw in other posts that many people had the same problem but the answers arent very useful, do you know what version of the plugin is good to achieve what II want?

Comment: I am not familiar with Intel xdk but from what I read in their docs, it is possible to use Cordova CLI with it. Can you go to your terminal and change directory to where your cordova project is and execute `cordova plugins ls` just to check whether `cordova-plugin-file` is added correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try but I saw the problem is the onDeviceReady because is never fired. Do you know why or what can I do to fire onDeviceReady?

Comment: I think Cordova is still undefined. Always make sure that `cordova.js` is present by adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`. Also, try to log what `window.Cordova` is outputting in the console.